# Multiple projects, building wrong project first and then breaking on deploy - Visual Studio 2022 - Community

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, multiple-projects

I have two projects. One for my backend (C#), one for my front end (Angular)
in my build properties, I have the order with which they need to build set.

[image]

the ports are set for localhost:7049 for the backend and localhost:4200 for the front end
However, when I start the build, in the output I get this:

[image]

there are no errors and the server never starts or deploys (according to the output)
So then it brings up the Angular project, which works fine.
then if I close the command prompt that has the publishing for the angular stuff, I get this pop up error:

[image]

if I click continue, it builds and deploys the backend code. Then I can right click the front end and go to Debug > Start new Instance and then they both work.

Obviously this is not ideal and not how it should work. So before I can continue working on this, I have to figure it out.

I have tried several things, some of which was repairing Visual Studio, reinstalling it, changing build order, changin dependencies under the property page in the first screenshot. I have tried changing ports, a lot of things.

Any suggestions on what to try next would be super helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was my node version. as of the date of making this version 18.13 was the version I had.

I found the answer from this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1109248/cant-start-frontend-and-backend-projects-at-the-sa

long story short. my node version wasn't playing well with the multiple projects so I uninstalled node and installed version 16.16.0:

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v16.16.0/

and then it was working